# open excel file from Weka?

Tags: excel, csv, weka

How to convert from excel to CSV to opened with weka "arff file"? I know that I should save file in csv"coma delimeted" and open it with weka.
But my problem when i do that I see all attribute convert to one attribute

This Screenshot for file , after exporting my data from Excel to CSV then I opened it in a plain text editor (Notepad++)!

```
> Student Track ;Elective course ;Student level;Elective course grade;IC Selm;ARAB;MATH106 Integral Calculus  ;MATH 244 Linear Algebra;CSC 113 Computer Programming (2);IT 221 Computer Organization & Assembly Language;IT 211 HCI (1);IT212 Data Structures;IT 224 Networks(1);IT 321 Computer Architecture ;IT 311 Web Applications;IT 323 Software Engineering (2);IT 325 Operating Systems ;IT 324 Information Security      ;IT 351 Wireless & Mobile Computing;IT 331 Database Management Systems ;IT 434 Data Warehousing & Data Mining;IT 453 Information Security & Assurance;IT 422 Intelligent Systems;IT 424 Networks (2);IT 419 Ethical Issues in Information ;IT 443 Advanced HCI (2);IT 454 Computer Forensics;IT 361 E-commerce;IT 342 Multimedia;IT 352 Network Security;IT 496 Project (1);IT 497 Project (2) ;IT 499 Seminar ;Free;Student GPA ( Semester );Student GPA (Cumulative );
Network & Security;IT 454 Computer forensic ;8;B+;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;1;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;4.75 - 5;4.75 - 5;
Network & Security;IT 454 Computer forensic ;8;B+;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;1;1;1;1;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;4.75 - 5;4.75 - 5;
Data Management;IT 332  Distributed Systems;8;A+;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;1;0;1;1;1;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;4.75 - 5;4.75 - 5;
Data Management;IT 332  Distributed Systems;8;B+;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;1;0;1;1;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;4 - 4.5;4 - 4.5;
Network & Security;IT 351 Wireless;6;A+;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;1;0;1;1;0;0;0;0;1;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;4.75 - 5;4.75 - 5;
Data Management;IT 332  Distributed Systems;8;A+;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;1;1;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;4.75 - 5;4.75 - 5;
```

Comment: Those aren't commas, they're semi-colons. You should be able to select semi-colon as the delimiter when you import to Excel and it will put the values into separate columns for you.

Comment: sorry can you explain more ? 
how can (( select semi-colon as the delimiter )) ?
@JoeMalpass
thank you

Comment: I misread your question, I thought you were importing to Excel, not exporting from it. I am not sure how Excel exported your file like that though - when I save a worksheet as a CSV from Excel and then open it in Notepad++ it is comma delimited, not semi-colon delimited. How are you exporting your data?

Answer (score 2):

Here's an idea:

If you had Weka 3.7, you could install a Package called "WekaExcel" which is an "official" Weka package, so no extra configuring required than a simple mouse click for the combined download+installation.

WekaExcel installs the open-Source "Apache Poi" conversion tool, which is a jar-File. 
So check your Weka Version, and whether you'll need administrative preferences to modify the directory where your Weka resides.

The WekaExcel package seems to be a bit fragile when dealing with large worksheets, and sensitive to, for instance, data-Type inconsistencies in the Columns. It creates cryptic error messages. And I don't know how to convert Excel-Date/Datetime Values to humanreadable datetimes.

But for small, simple worksheets, it seems to work. There are now entries for Excel .xlsx and .xls files in the the Preprocess/OpenFile Dialog-Box.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Export Excel to csv, and import to Weka csv. Attention change separation marked "," to ";" when import csv to Weka

Answer (score 0):

You pass from excel to `.txt` file (copy/paste), replace the `blank` by `,` save the file as `.csv`, or open it with excel and save it as `.csv`.